# Excel VBA code to download images in MacOS runs without error but doesnt download any image

Tags: excel, vba, macos, image, imagedownload

I need to download images using excel vba in macOS the part i guess is having error is that this function doesnt download image. I have never made vba code for MacOS so can anybody tell me do i have to select any library for this code to work or i have used wrong library.

```
 Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function popen64 Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "popen" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As Long

Public Function DownloadURLtoFile(sSourceURL As String, _
sLocalFileName As String) As Boolean
 
Debug.Print sSourceURL
Debug.Print sLocalFileName
DownloadURLtoFile = popen64(0&, _
    sSourceURL, sLocalFileName, &H10, 0&) = 0&

End Function
```

Thanks in advance....

I am using this way to call this function and checked filepath is correct.

```
FolderString = FolderString & FirstName & "_" & LastName & ".jpg"
Debug.Print FolderString
    If DownloadURLtoFile(cell.Value, FolderString) Then
        cell.Offset(, 3).Value = "Successfully downloaded"
    Else
        cell.Offset(, 3).Value = "Error - no download"
    End If
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?  Are you passing a full path to `sLocalFileName` ?

Comment: Added way of calling function and full path in the above code. Surprisingly DownloadURL toFile returns true so my sheet gets value  "Successfully downloaded" but no image in download folder..... However folder creation function is working properly. I tried deleting folder and it gets created.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a Mac so I have no more suggestions/questions....

Comment: @AnmolKumar do you get any solution of this or NOT? if you have solved it, will you mind answer you own question?